# Как изменить подписи с английского языка на русский у video.js player?

Tags: javascript, html

используемая библиотека video.js, версии 8.3.0

вот код, но он не срабатывает:

```
      // Переопределение строк на русский язык
  videojs.addLanguage('ru', {
    "Play": "Воспроизвести",
    "Pause": "Пауза",
    "Mute": "Отключить звук",
    "Unmute": "Включить звук",
    "Picture-in-Picture": "Видео в видео"
  });

  // Установка языка "ru" как языка по умолчанию
  videojs.options.language = 'ru';
  // Initialize Video.js player
  var player = videojs('video');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Как изменить подписи с английского языка на русский у video.js player?

Я взял пример https://translated.turbopages.org/proxy_u/en-ru.ru.e1708e20-64ccfd63-df10b196-74722d776562/https/www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-set-up-different-languages-in-video-js-player

Добавил твой объект...

Все получилось.

```js
videojs.addLanguage('ru', {
  "Play": "Воспроизвести",
  "Pause": "Пауза",
  "Mute": "Отключить звук",
  "Unmute": "Включить звук",
  "Picture-in-Picture": "Видео в видео"
})


// добавил еще объект с языком
var player = videojs('my-video', {language: 'ru'});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Setup Languages in Video.js Player</title>
  <link href="//vjs.zencdn.net/8.3.0/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/8.3.0/video.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <video id="my-video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls="true" autoplay="true" muted="true" preload="auto" poster="assets/sample.png" width="560" height="340" data-setup="{}">
      <source  src="https://www.tutorialspoint.com/videos/sample720.mp4"  type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: У меня все на английском, это из-за английского языка в браузере?

Comment: @OliverPatterson, я немного изменил пример...

Comment: Спасибо. Все сработало.